# GWT-Editors and sub-editors

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-editors

I'm trying to run an example of Editors with sub-editors.
When flushing the parent the value of child editor is null.
The classes are Person and Address.
The main editor is:

```java
    // editor fields
public TextField firstname;
public TextField lastname;
public NumberField<Integer> id;

public AddressEditor address = new AddressEditor();

public PersonEditor(Person p){
    asWidget();
}

@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    setWidth(400);
    setBodyStyle("padding: 5px;");
    setHeaderVisible(false);

    VerticalLayoutContainer c = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

    id = new NumberField<Integer>(new IntegerPropertyEditor());
    // id.setName("id");
    id.setFormat(NumberFormat.getFormat("0.00"));
    id.setAllowNegative(false);
    c.add(new FieldLabel(id, "id"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));

    firstname = new TextField();
    // firstname.setName("firstname");
    c.add(new FieldLabel(firstname, "firstname"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));

    lastname = new TextField();
    lastname.setName("lastname");
    c.add(new FieldLabel(lastname, "lastname"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));

    c.add(address);
    add(c);
    return this;
```

The sub-editor:

```java
public class AddressEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Address> {

private AddressProperties props = GWT.create(AddressProperties.class);
private ListStore<Address> store = new ListStore<Address>(props.key());
ComboBox<Address> address;

public AddressEditor() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        store.add(new Address("city" + i));
    address = new ComboBox<Address>(store, props.nameLabel());

    address.setAllowBlank(false);
    address.setForceSelection(true);
    address.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
    initWidget(address);
}
```

And this is where the Driver is created:

```java
private HorizontalPanel hp;

private Person googleContact;
PersonDriver driver = GWT.create(PersonDriver.class);

public void onModuleLoad() {

    hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.setSpacing(10);

    googleContact = new Person();
    PersonEditor pe = new PersonEditor(googleContact);

    driver.initialize(pe);
    driver.edit(googleContact);

    TextButton save = new TextButton("Save");
    save.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            googleContact = driver.flush();
            System.out.println(googleContact.getFirstname() + ", " + googleContact.getAddress().getCity());
            if (driver.hasErrors()) {
                new MessageBox("Please correct the errors before saving.").show();
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

The value of googleContact.getFirstname() is filled but googleContact.getAddress() is always null.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddressEditor` needs to map to the `Address` model - presently, it doesn't seem to, unless `Address` only has one getter/setter, called `getAddress()` and `setAddress(Address)`, which wouldn't really make a lot of sense.

If you want just a `ComboBox<Address>` (which implements `Editor<Address>` already), consider putting that combo in the `PersonEditor` directly. Otherwise, you'll need to add `@Path("")` to the `AddressEditor.address` field, to indicate that it should be directly editing the value itself, and not a sub property (i.e. `person.getAddress().getAddress()`).

Another way to build an address editor would be to list each of the properties of the `Address` type in the `AddressEditor`. This is what the driver is expecting by default, so it is confused when it sees a field called 'address'.

Two quick thoughts on the code itself: there is no need to pass a person into the `PersonEditor` - thats the job of the driver itself. Second, your editor fields do not need to be `public`, they just can't be `private`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was confusing A little bit how to set up the sub-object. I tried to add @Path("") ComboBox<Address> address; but it didn't work. I put everything in one class and it worked great. Thanks again!

Comment: @Berna, if you think this is a valid answer, you should accept it by clicking the empty checkmark